# Convert back WrappedArray from string to WrappedArray, then to Json

Tags: pyspark, hive

I have a hive table which was given as a sample data as an output of another process which we don't have access to.

While preparing certain apis which take this data as input, I noticed a column containing WrappedArray, but it is of string type in the sample Hive Table

`WrappedArray(Map(keyphrase -> england somerset bridgwater bridgwater b&bs, cluster_id -> 3, adjusted_importance -> 0.9403), Map(keyphrase -> bridgwater tourism bridgwater hotels bed, cluster_id -> 3, adjusted_importance -> 0.922), Map(keyphrase -> airbnb bridgwater, cluster_id -> 3, adjusted_importance -> 0.9057), Map(keyphrase -> bridgwater b&b prices, cluster_id -> 3, adjusted_importance -> 0.8954), Map(keyphrase -> holiday inn express bridgwater m, cluster_id -> 3, adjusted_importance -> 0.8876), Map(keyphrase -> old vicarage hotel bridgwater, cluster_id -> 3, adjusted_importance -> 0.8823), Map(keyphrase -> bridgwater popular, cluster_id...`

I am looking at trying to convert it somehow back to WrappedArray type and then to Json type.

Is it possible to do it in Hive or Spark SQL ?

I tried like this

```
select cast(aggregate_extracts as 'WrappedArray') from project_bex_seo.expedia_serp_page_content_relevancy_gap_page_level_uk_dummy limit 10
```

At the moment I am restricted to use this as the source.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure, but in think `WrappedArray` is not implemented in pyspark yet.